# Acessing an array from a header file crashes program

Tags: c++, arrays

I recently finished a course on C++, to test to see what I knew from it I decided to start work on a operating system simulation, it seemed to be going fairly well up till I tried to implement a multiple users system by using a array to store user names, from which the user will select one and it will go into their user. However the problem with it that when I try and modify the array in the header file in the source file the program crashes.
header files:

```
#ifndef UBUNTU_LOGIN_H
#define UBUNTU_LOGIN_H
#include "Ubuntu_UserDetails.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Ubuntu_Login: protected UserDetails
{
public:
  void Ubuntu_UserCreation();
  void Ubuntu_login();
};

#endif // UBUNTU_LOGIN_H
```

```
#ifndef UBUNTU_USERDETAILS_H
#define UBUNTU_USERDETAILS_H
#include "Ubuntu_login.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class UserDetails
{
protected:
  std::string username;
  std::string password;
  std::string users[0];
};

#endif // UBUNTU_USERDETAILS_H
```

source files:

```
#include "Ubuntu_login.h"
#include "Ubuntu_UserDetails.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void Ubuntu_Login::Ubuntu_UserCreation()
{
  std::cout << "\t _____________" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "\t|Create a user|\n" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Enter a username:" << std::endl;
  std::getline(std::cin, username);

  std::cout << "Enter a password:" << std::endl;
  std::getline(std::cin, password);

  users[0] = username;
  std::cout << users[0] << std::endl;

  std::cout << "User created successfully" << std::endl;
}


void Ubuntu_Login::Ubuntu_login()
{
  std::cout << "\t ______" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "\t|Log in|\n" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Select user" << std::endl;
}
```

```
#include "Ubuntu_login.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
 Ubuntu_Login UO;
 UO.Ubuntu_UserCreation();
 UO.Ubuntu_login();

}
```

when I try to run it I get as far as the initial password entry then the program crashed, I assume this is due to a stack overflow, but I wouldn't know how to solve it. Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated as well as general help on the code as a whole :) .

also the reason I have not included things like storing passwords as hashes or not echoing the password is simply because I don't know the syntax to do it and I wanted to try to do the things I knew how to do first then add additional features later, so don't expect great code :P

Comment: Hint: how many elements are there in your array?

Comment: Hint: you'll need strcpy to copy your string

Comment: I can only seem to get it to work if I use certain numbers in the users = user name code the users declaration seems to not affect the code, for instance if I set users[10] It works if I set users[2] username or if I set users[6] and users[6] = username. It seems strange that it would only work with certain numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::vector<std::string> users`

And then just `users.push_back(username)` to it. Dynamic array is suitable here.

Comment: How would I print the contents of a vector?

Comment: You would have to loop over all elements inside the vector and print them separately. But if you're learning c++ I suggest you find another way. Before you know you'll be using vectors all over the place just to store some stuff.

Comment: would using a for loop be a good way of doing that or would you recommend something else?

Comment: C++11 has range-for loops. They are really useful: for(std::string& user : users)

Answer (score 0):

In your `Ubuntu_UserDetails.h` you have this data member in the `UserDetails` class:

> ```
> std::string users[0];
> ```

Then in a source file, you have this assignment:

> ```
> users[0] = username;
> ```

If you access an item in an array with index 0, the array must have at least one element. In fact, index 0 refers to the *first* item in the array.

So, the users array should be defined as having some bigger size.

But, much better, consider using a convenient C++ container class for vectors, like **`std::vector`**.

So, in your header file, you can define a data member like this:

```
// Instead of:
//   std::string users[0]
//
std::vector<std::string> userNames; // probably better than "users"
```

Then you can add new items to the vector using its `push_back` or `emplace_back` methods.